# Error while compiling c++ code in gcc compiler in macOS

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, sublimetext3

I have been trying to setup a c++ code execution environment in my macOS. I am using sublime text editor. I have installed gcc compiler(v11) and then i have created a link to g++ that points to g++-11 using command `cd /usr/local/bin/` and then linking it using `ln -s g++-11 g++` and i have added a new build system for c++ execution. The build file is

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp",
 // "keys": ["ctrl+q"], 
    // "command": "cancel_build" 
}
```

and saved it to default `user`. Now when I am trying to run the build it is giving an error `ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.5) than being linked (11.3)` .
I have tried to look around this but haven't found solution to it .
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's a warning not an error. That means it still linked it but it's giving you some information which may or may not be a problem. The library you are linking was built for macOS version 11.5. Your build is linking for macOS version 11.3. There might be something in the library which depends upon 11.5. What version of macOS are you running on? Where did the library come from?

Comment: Note - you don't need `.exe` anywhere in the `"cmd"` line, as macOS doesn't use `.exe` files - only Windows does.

Comment: i am using macOS big sur and installed gcc from brew . how to link it properly then @lurker